# Marklogic - how find any record doesn't has a field

Tags: marklogic

I have some XML that has missing `citationDate` field elements in collections.

How to find any records (documents in collections) that don't have `citationDate` field element.  How can I construct query?

```
let $uris := cts:uris(
                     (),
                     (),
                     cts:collection-query
                         (("/collection/research","/collection/IACS")
                      and DONT have citationDate field
                  )
return count($uris)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for the not-query combined with the element-query:

```
cts:not-query(cts:element-query(xs:QName("citationDate"), cts:true-query()))
```

You combine it with your collection-query using a `cts:and-query`.

HTH!